# junit.Assert.assertTrue fails, but only when I compile the module?

Tags: java, maven, junit

**Summary**

An unit test assertion (`junit.Assert.assertTrue`) is failing only when I compile the module (`mvn clean install`).
However, it's not failing if I run the `JUnit` tests on Eclipse, and when I see what the function does I can't understand why the compilation fails. 
Does anyone have any idea on how I could troubleshoot what's going wrong?

Below all the details for the interested readers :)

**Function to test:**

I have a function with the following body:

```
public static boolean isBatchOfProducts(List<?> products) {
    boolean areBatches = (products != null && products.size() != 0);
    for (Object product : products) {
        areBatches = areBatches && product instanceof XmlProducts;
        if (areBatches) {
            XmlProducts xmlProducts = (XmlProducts)product;
            areBatches = areBatches && !xmlProducts.getXmlProduct().isEmpty();              
        }
    }
    return areBatches;
}
```

The purpose of the function is to return `true/false`, given a generic input `List<?> products`:

- If this list is not `null` nor `empty`...
- ... if every object of this list is an instance of `XmlProducts`...
- ... and if for every `XmlProducts` instance, the list of `XmlProduct` contained is not empty...

... then the function should return `true`, `false` in any other case.

**Unit test**

In order to cover this behavior, I've added some unit tests and one of them is the following:

```
@Test
public void testListOfOneEmptyXmlProducts() {
    List<Object> listToPrice = BatchPricingHelper.createPricingApiInputEmptyBatchXmlProducts();
    assertTrue(!ProductUtils.isBatchOfProducts(listToPrice));
}
```

The output given by `BatchPricingHelper.createPricingApiInputEmptyBatchXmlProducts()`, as the name says, it's just a `List<?>` containing only one `XmlProducts` which has no `XmlProduct` in its list (`getXmlProduct()` is empty).

**When I run from Eclipse**

I can easily see the unit test is green: the collection doesn't respect all the criteria to be a batch of products, hence the function returns `false` and I `assertTrue` on `!false`:

[image]

**When I compile from Maven**

If I compile the module using Maven, specifically the command `mvn clean install` on the directory, I get the following error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running mycompany.sdk.pricing.impl.PricingSessionTest
Tests run: 15, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.311 sec <<< FAILURE! - in mycompany.sdk.pricing.impl.PricingSessionTest
testListOfOneEmptyXmlProducts(mycompany.sdk.pricing.impl.PricingSessionTest)  Time elapsed: 0.004 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError:
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:54)
        at mycompany.sdk.pricing.impl.PricingSessionTest.testListOfOneEmptyXmlProducts(PricingSessionTest.java:279)
```

... causing of course a `BUILD FAILURE`. I've tried to add into the unit test the whole body of the function I'm testing, and printing every output in order to see where the evaluation was failing:

```
@Test
public void testListOfOneEmptyXmlProducts() {
    List<Object> listToPrice = BatchPricingHelper.createPricingApiInputEmptyBatchXmlProducts();
    boolean areBatches = (listToPrice != null && listToPrice.size() != 0);
    System.out.println("list not null and not empty: " + areBatches);
    for (Object product : listToPrice) {
        areBatches = areBatches && product instanceof XmlProducts;
        System.out.println("product is instance of XmlProducts: " + areBatches);
        if (areBatches) {
            XmlProducts xmlProducts = (XmlProducts)product;
            areBatches = areBatches && !xmlProducts.getXmlProduct().isEmpty(); 
            System.out.println("list of XmlProduct is not empty: " + areBatches);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Final result: " + areBatches);
    assertTrue(!ProductUtils.isBatchOfProducts(listToPrice));
}
```

The strange thing is that I can see in the Command Prompt output that every evaluation goes well, and it's really just the `assertTrue` which doesn't work:

```
Running mycompany.sdk.pricing.impl.PricingSessionTest
list not null and not empty: true << CORRECT!
product is instance of XmlProducts: true << CORRECT!
list of XmlProduct is not empty: false << CORRECT, THE LIST IS EMPTY!
Final result: false << CORRECT, IT SHOULD RETURN FALSE!

---BUT STILL THE FAILURE BELOW!---

Tests run: 15, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.311 sec <<< FAILURE! - in mycompany.sdk.pricing.impl.PricingSessionTest
testListOfOneEmptyXmlProducts(mycompany.sdk.pricing.impl.PricingSessionTest)  Time elapsed: 0.004 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError:
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:54)
        at mycompany.sdk.pricing.impl.PricingSessionTest.testListOfOneEmptyXmlProducts(PricingSessionTest.java:279)
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding debug output to the `isBatchOfProducts` method itself, rather than copy-pasting its code elsewhere. Then you'll be able to track at which point during the real execution of a method `areBatches` turns to false.

Comment: Rather than using `assertTrue(!condition)` why not use `assertFalse(condition)`? Also, you never break out of the `for` loop in `isBatchOfProducts` which means `areBatches` is the result of testing the _last_ element of the list. In other words, an element could set `areBatches` to `false` but if the last element makes it `true` the result of the method is `true`. Is this intended behavior?

Comment: @Slaw you're right, `assertFalse` is more readable, didn't solve the issue but yet I've used it for readibility. Regarding the function itself, `areBatches` is initialized only on top of the function and then it's all the time saying `areBatches = areBatches && someothercondition`. Hence, once `areBatches` becomes `false` once, it can't be `true` anymore. Even though it's useless to keep on looping when we already know the result, I'll add a `break` as well :)

Comment: Ah, I failed to take the `&&` into account. But yes, it's more efficient to `break` once `false` :). As for the question at hand, I second  _default locale_: Try adding debug output or attaching a debugger and stepping through.

Comment: @defaultlocale thanks to your comment, I've figured out what was wrong! In fact the function `isBatchOfProducts` was defined in another module and imported into this one. Thanks to the unit tests I've spotted a fix to do, but I forgot to recompile the other module. Eclipse had a local copy of the new `.jar`, but when compiling manually the single module `mvn` wasn't detecting the dependency change and using the old version of the function. It's when I went to add the `System.out.println` in the function as you suggested that I figured that out! If you write an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! I've suspected something like this, tbh. I suggest that you post an answer yourself, as it turns out, the question couldn't be resolved without a piece of external information about your setup. P.S. This method can be simplified with [`Stream.allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) or with early return statements if streams are not an option for some reason.

Comment: @defaultlocale thanks for the suggestion, I will have a look at Stream.allMatch. I vote for you posting the answer, you should get the reputation reward you deserve!  But if don't see your answer in few hours I'll post it myself, thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, it was just a compilation issue.

- I have written the function `isBatchOfProducts()` in the class `ProductUtils` which was in a different Maven project (say Project X)
- I have written the unit test `testListOfOneEmptyXmlProducts()` into the Project Y
- Thanks to this unit test, I've spotted a bug and changed the code of `isBatchOfProducts()`
- I have re-run the unit test and it was green (because Eclipse was apparently compiling behind the scenes the changes I did into the Project X)
- I have tried to compile the Project Y, but it was failing because still pointing to the old version of the `.jar`

Basically, a non-problem. Remember always to recompile what you change :)

Answer (score -1):

What about more parentheses : `assertTrue(!(ProductUtils.isBatchOfProducts(listToPrice)));` ?

Comment: Just tried that, but it's not the issue, thanks anyway.